Why don't all of my messages get published on the RabbitMQ queue?
I wanted to publish 1 million messages on the RabbitMQ queue but just 999,429 messages were published.
This number is not fixed. I run the application with a million messages every time, but not once did all of them appear on the queue.
Here is the source code of the console application that I use to publish my messages:
public class Program
{
    private static List<Message> messages = new();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                Message message = new Message
                {
                    Content = new Content
                    {
                        Data = "hgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;klshdghgsdjghdskjghdsjkhgkdjshgjksdhgsdkhga;fdsfdsfsdfdsfdsfdsfsdfdsdgsdgsdgdsgksdhglkdshglkjsdhglksdfsdfsdfsdfsfsdfdsdgsdgsdgdsgksdhglkdshglkjsdhglksdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsdfdsf"
                    }
                };
                messages.Add(message);
            }

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("PATH", append: true);

            writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:ffffff"));
  
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                HostName = "IP",
                Port = 5672,
                VirtualHost = "VH",
                UserName = "UserName",
                Password = "Password",
            };

            using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            using var channel = connection.CreateModel();

            channel.ConfirmSelect();
            
            connection.ConnectionBlocked += (sender, args) =>
            {
               writer.WriteLine("Connection blocked due to flow control. Slowing down publishing... " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:ffffff"));
            };

            connection.ConnectionUnblocked += (sender, args) =>
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Connection unblocked. Resuming publishing... " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:ffffff"));
            };
            channel.BasicReturn += (sender, args) =>
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Message was returned by RabbitMQ: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(args.Body.ToArray()) + "\n" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:ffffff"));
            };

            channel.BasicAcks += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Message successfully acknowledged by RabbitMQ. Delivery tag: " + eventArgs.DeliveryTag + "   " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh: mm:ss: ffffff"));
            };

            channel.BasicNacks += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Message NOT acknowledged by RabbitMQ. Delivery tag: " + eventArgs.DeliveryTag + "   " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh: mm:ss: ffffff"));
            };
            IBasicProperties properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
            properties.Headers = new Dictionary<string, object?>
            {
                { "UID", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},
                { "UserId", 6 },
                { "Serial", "A2AB19" },
                { "MemoryId", 1 },
                { "DeliveryMethod", 2 },
                { "IP", "::1" }
            };

            foreach (Message message in messages)
            {
                byte[] payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message.Content.Data);
                channel.BasicPublish("my_exchange", "my.routingkey.publish", mandatory: true, properties, payload);
            }

            writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:ffffff"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("PATH", append: true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}

Also, BasicNacks, BasicReturn, ConnectionBlocked, and ConnectionUnblocked events aren't raised at all.
Are there any other events that I should use to get these missed messages?
